Azure DevOps Release Pipeline: Apparent contradiction between Releases tab and Deployments tab as to which is the current release
We have a release pipeline with several stages.  I'm trying to determine what the release is that's currently deployed to the UAT stage.  It seems that the Releases tab and the Deployments tab for the release pipeline show different releases as the one currently deployed to UAT.  Which is correct?
Here is the Releases tab, filtered to show the currently deployed releases.  It seems to indicate release 6.0.3571.0.01 is the current release in UAT:

Here is the Deployments tab, filtered to show only UAT.  It seems to show release 6.0.3582.0.01 is the most recent release deployed to UAT:

Which is the actual release in UAT, 6.0.3571.0.01 or 6.0.3582.0.01?

Normally, the Currently deployed for each stage is based on the latest run of each stage.
For example, release-1 triggered before release-2, but the UAT stage of release-1 runs after that of release-2, at this time, the Currently deployed for UAT stage is marked on release-1 rather than release-2.
On the Deployments tab, it just lists all the existing deployments on all stages or the specified stage by filter.
For your case, if you have checks (Pre-deployment approvals or Gates) set on the UAT stage, when the checks of UAT stage of release 6.0.3582.0.01 got passed before that of release 6.0.3571.0.01, the UAT stage of release 6.0.3582.0.01 would run before that of 6.0.3571.0.01. So, the deployment of UAT stage in release 6.0.3571.0.01 will be considered as the latest deployment (currently deployed) for UAT stage.
Similarly, if you manually start the UAT stage of release 6.0.3582.0.01 before that of release 6.0.3571.0.01, the deployment of UAT stage in release 6.0.3571.0.01 also will be considered as the latest deployment (currently deployed) for UAT stage.

So, to determine the current release in UAT, I can effectively ignore the Deployments tab.  It'll just be the release highlighted in Currently deployed.  Is that correct?

@SimonElms, Yes, you can get the Currently deployed (latest deployed) of each stage from the Releases tab where the latest deployed of each stage is highlighted.

@SimonElms, If you want the latest deployed of a stage is located on the latest release, you need to ensure the latest run of that stage is started on the latest release after the previously triggered releases.
